# Using sapply with switch

Tags: r

Lets say I have the following case:

I am trying to apply a switch statement to each term in test where `test = c("AA","bb")` and `mapping = c("AA"=5,"bb"=7)`

If I do

```
sapply(test, switch, mapping )
```

I get

```
    AA bb
AA  5  5
bb  7  7
```

instead of `c(5,7)` like I want. Is there any way to modify `sapply(test,switch,...)` such that the first 2 arguments are still test and switch and I am able to pass in a vector for the mapping?

Comment: anything wrong with just doing `mapping[test]`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'll make it an answer then, you can just do:

```
mapping[test]
# AA bb 
# 5  7
```

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work for **using sapply with switch**. But frankly, flodel's response is simplest.

```
test<-c(test,test)
sapply(test,function(x) do.call("switch",as.list(c(x,mapping))))
# AA  bb  AA  bb 
#"5" "7" "5" "7"
```